# Mongoose: Don't push to array if document exists

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, updates

In the below code, I'm creating a checkin document which I then reference in the user document, on top with a car reference (in the user's collection). What I'm trying to achieve is to skip the insert to the array if the car already exists.

How to check it? Or should I work with the model, and define a uniqueness reference in the `cars[]` array?

```
router.post('/', (req, res, err) => {
  var checkin = new Checkin(req.body);

  checkin._id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId();

  checkin.save()
    .then((checkinDoc) => {
      return User.findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: ObjectID(checkin.user) },
        { $push: { checkins: checkinDoc._id, cars: checkin.car } },
        { new: true }
      )
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.send(err);
    });
});
```

My `user.js` model

```
[...]

cars: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Car'
  }],

[...]
```

Comment: Instead of `$push` use `$addToSet`

Comment: Awesome. Thanks @chridam. Exactly what I was looking for.